# "Me gustaría" vs "Quería"

Tags: gramática

I am confused by which to use; *"me gustaría"* or *"quería"*?

For example:

> I would like a bottle of red wine, please.

In Spain they say:

> ***Quería*** una botella de vino tinto, por favor.

But in other places they say:

> ***Me gustaría*** una botella de vino tinto, por favor.

Which is correct?  Or, does it even matter?

Comment: Most everywhere you go the most common ways to order are simply "quiero," "dame,"  "me das," "me regalas"  etc.

Answer (score 1):

Both cases are correct, but let me clarify two points:

> *Quería una botella de vino tinto, por favor.*

Could also be in this case:

> ***Querría*** una botella de vino tinto, por favor.

And the second one:

> *Me gustaría una botella de vino tinto, por favor.*

I would add a verb after *"Me gustaría"*, for example:

> *Me gustaría **tomar** una botella de vino tinto, por favor.*

In this case, drinking a bottle of wine sounds exaggerated, but the point is to add a verb as I told you, it sounds better this way.

Comment: for me the use of queria instead of "me gustaria" sounds incorrect. 
as queria means "I wanted" while "me gustaria" is "I would like"

Comment: Thats why I also added "Querría" @Mike